# Is there an XSL "contains" directive?

Tags: xslt

I have the following snippet of XSL:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:variable name="hhref" select="link" />
    <xsl:variable name="pdate" select="pubDate" />
    <xsl:if test="hhref not contains '1234'">
      <li>
        <a href="{$hhref}" title="{$pdate}">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </a>
      </li>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

The if statement does not work because I haven't been able to work out the syntax for contains. How would I correctly express that xsl:if?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Sure there is! For instance:

```
<xsl:if test="not(contains($hhref, '1234'))">
  <li>
    <a href="{$hhref}" title="{$pdate}">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:if>
```

The syntax is: `contains(stringToSearchWithin, stringToSearchFor)`

Answer (score 9):

**Use the standard [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) function [contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-contains).**

**Function**: *boolean* **contains**(string, string)

The [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-contains) function returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false

Answer (score 7):

there is indeed an xpath contains function it should look something like:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="item">
  <xsl:variable name="hhref" select="link" />
  <xsl:variable name="pdate" select="pubDate" />
  <xsl:if test="not(contains($hhref,'1234'))">
    <li>
      <a href="{$hhref}" title="{$pdate}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like...

```
<xsl:if test="contains($hhref, '1234')">
```

(not tested)

See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp) (always a good reference BTW)

Comment: the link is broken now

Comment: Indeed. I found no replacement on the site. But my answer is still valid ;-)

Comment: maybe this one https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp

Answer (score 2):

From [Zvon.org XSLT Reference](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/index.html):

```
XPath function: boolean contains (string, string)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:if test="not contains(hhref,'1234')">
```

Comment: Does the not operator work without a parentheses? If so, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Cerebrus It does in XSLT 2.0, but not in 1.0

Comment: is the $ prefix in hhref optional?