# Test for a value inside a string

Tags: string, testing, xslt, parameters

Let's say I have the string of "2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009" that is assigned to the parameter of "show".

Now, this does work:

```
<xsl:if test="$show='2004'">
    //stuff
</xsl:if>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<xsl:if test="$show='2005'">
    //stuff
</xsl:if>
```

I'm not sure how to test for part of a string like that. Any idea?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569908/is-there-an-xsl-contains-directive

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `contains`.

```
<xsl:if test="contains($show, '2004')">
    //stuff
</xsl:if>
```

A more detailed example, which will print **yes**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="show" select="'2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009'"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($show, '2004')">yes</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($show, '2004'))">no</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have the following: `<grp1>...</grp1><grp2>...</grp2>...` and I am checking for it like this: `<xsl:for-each select="substr(name(.),1,3)='grp'">`. I keep getting XPath syntax error. Can you please help? http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp5/1. I would like to take the content for each `grp#`

Answer (score 4):

You're needing the contains() XPath function.  You can use it like this:

```
<xsl:if test="contains($show,'2005')">
  //stuff
</xsl:if>
```